# Merging two files line by line Java

Tags: java

Is there a more efficient way than i'm currently using, to merge two files line by line appending the line from file2 onto file1?

If file1 contains

```
a1
b1
c1
```

And file2 contains

```
a2
b2
c2
```

Then the output file should contain

```
a1,a2
b1,b2
c1,c2
```

The current combineRecords method looks like

```
private FileSheet combineRecords(ArrayList<FileSheet> toCombine) throws IOException
{
    ArrayList<String> filepaths = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (FileSheet sheetIterator : toCombine)
    {
        filepaths.add(sheetIterator.filepath);
    }

    String filepathAddition = "";

    for (String s : filepaths)
    {
        filepathAddition = filepathAddition + s.split(".select.")[1].replace(".csv", "")  + ".";
    }

    String outputFilepath = subsheetDirectory + fileHandle.getName().split(".csv")[0] + ".select." + filepathAddition +  "csv";

    Log.log("Output filepath "  + outputFilepath);

    long mainFileLength = toCombine.get(0).recordCount();

    for (FileSheet f : toCombine)
    {
        int ordinal = toCombine.indexOf(f);

        if (toCombine.get(ordinal).recordCount() != mainFileLength)
        {
            Log.log("Error : Record counts for 0 + " + ordinal);
            return null;
        }
    }

    FileSheet finalValues;

    Log.log("Starting iteration streams");
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFilepath, false));

    List<BufferedReader> streams = new ArrayList<>();
    for (FileSheet j : toCombine)
    {
        streams.add(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(j.filepath)));
    }

    String finalWrite = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < toCombine.get(0).recordCount(); i++)
    {

        for (FileSheet j : toCombine)
        {
            int ordinal = toCombine.indexOf(j);

            finalWrite = finalWrite + streams.get(ordinal).readLine();

            if (toCombine.indexOf(j) != toCombine.size() - 1)
            {
                finalWrite = finalWrite + ",";
            }
            else
            {
                finalWrite = finalWrite + "\n";
            }
        }

        if (i % 1000 == 0 || i == toCombine.get(0).recordCount() - 1)
        {
            // out.write(finalWrite + "\n");
            Files.write(Paths.get(outputFilepath),(finalWrite).getBytes(),StandardOpenOption.APPEND);

            finalWrite = "";
        }           
    }
    out.close();


    Log.log("Finished combineRecords");

    finalValues = new FileSheet(outputFilepath,0);
    return finalValues;
}
```

I've tried both bufferedwriters and files.write, and they have similar times to create file3, both in the 1:30 minute range, but i'm not sure if the bottleneck is at reading or writing

The sample files i'm using are currently at 36,000 records, but the actual file i'll be using is ~650,000 so taking (if it scales linearly) 1625 seconds is completely unfeasible for this operation

Edit : I've modified the code to only open files once, rather than per iteration, however i'm now getting stream closed when skipping to the nth line
I thought that by doing `streams.get(ordinal).skip(i).findFirst().get();` would return a new stream instead of skipping then closing the stream

Edit 2 : Modified the code to use bufferedreaders instead of streams, and write to file every 1000 lines read, and thats determined that the bottleneck is reading, because it still takes ~1:30 to do

Comment: You should try write in memory buffer and after the loop write that once to the file. I guess it is going to be a little faster and, bonus, will no lock the file.

Comment: I wanted to do it line by line so it can scale to any size easily, i was working with a much larger sample file yesterday, doing everything in memory, and once it reached about 3 million lines it would overflow the heap
This whole class is for when its unfeasible to do things in memory

Comment: And if you do some flushes? You could use a StringBuilder, do some iterations and flush by certain value, using some condition like i % Xi == 0, where Xi is the memory buffer limit.

Comment: i'll modify the code and attempt that

Comment: Your code is hard to understand. It seems like you create a new Reader for each file for each line. This may be the cause for being very slow. Why don't you open each file once and then for each input file you read one line combine them and then write it. And then you read the next line for each file without closing the Reader instances in between.

Comment: I'll look up how to skip to the nth line with a bufferedreader

Comment: *"... i'm not sure if the bottleneck is at reading or writing ..."*  - Profile it!

Comment: Edited the code to open files once into a stream (badly) and now i'm getting an exception about the stream being closed when i try to skip to the nth element in it

Comment: Why do you even need to skip? I don't see any skip in your code, nor any explanation of why it is needed

Comment: I would start doing two things: `out.write(finalWrite);` instead of `Files.write...`. Then instead of `finalWrite = finalWrite + `... Use a `StringBuilder`. At the moment, you are creating thousands of new strings in a loop. That probably isn't a huge hit, but it is worth trying to avoid. And might just cut off some time in the loop.

Comment: So that i dont read line 1 on the first iteration, then line 1 and 2 on the second, 1,2,3 on the third
I'm in the process of making large sweeping changes to the code that calls this method to render it obsolete and hopefully speed things up that way

Comment: There's better way to avoid this, such as keeping your readers' state between each read : first iteration read first line of both files, second iteration when you read the next line of each file it'll be the second one

Comment: Why don't you open both files, read the lines, and write them (comma separated) to a third file?

Comment: Like i said in a previous comment, i've now made huge changes to the surrounding code to render this stuff not needed
My time to 'combine' two records has gone from 90s to 417ms

Answer (score 1):

First of all concating string using `+` operator is ok when it is not under loop. But when you want to merge strings in a loop you should use `StringBuilder` for better performance.

Second thing which you can improve you can write to file at the end like:

```
StringBuilder finalWrite = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < toCombine.get(0).recordCount(); i++)
{

    for (FileSheet j : toCombine)
    {
        int ordinal = toCombine.indexOf(j);

        finalWrite.append(streams.get(ordinal).readLine());

        if (toCombine.indexOf(j) != toCombine.size() - 1)
        {
            finalWrite.append(",");
        }
        else
        {
            finalWrite.append("\n");
        }
    }           
}

Files.write(Paths.get(outputFilepath), finalWrite.toString().getBytes());
```

Comment: When scaled up to my larger sample file, finalWrite could be the length of 16 * 5,000,000 strings of arbitrary length when done using that method, thats why i've got it writing more often than just at the end

Comment: Mmm understand, could you please at least make changes in your code to use StringBuilder for all type of concat and share the results? I'll think about writing

Comment: I've made large changes to the code to render this entire process obsolete, should i just delete the question as it's no longer necessary?

Comment: Probably yes, but 1 last thing. Please dont use `Files.write` in a loop, it is performance killer because it opens file writes and closes. instead use PrintWriter.


`FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("yourfile.txt", true);` 
`BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);` 
`PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw))`

Comment: I wasnt sure which to use, hence i've got a random buffered writer sitting around in the code with it's write commented
I'll use bufferedwriter in the future for stuff inside loops, thanks for the tip